# Java conditional not working correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

I am putting if statements in java code for finding out if the [pcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) file contains certain string or not, if yes then don't show that string in my else condition but I am still getting that string in my else condition. Can anyone tell me what can be the possible problems?

my code

```
      String a=new String(packet.data);
      if(a.contains("image/"))
      {

      }
      else
      {
           System.out.println(a);
      }
```

Comment: On first glance it looks fine. Perhaps send the string to System.out before testing it, to make sure it reall does contain what you think it does?

Comment: `if`s are not loops. Also it's very hard to tell what exactly do you want.

Comment: What's the content of a?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ Martin Klinke  its a pcap file

Comment: `if` statements are buggy, they only work half the time ;-)

Comment: What is printed in the else statement?

Comment: what if `a` never really contains `image/`?

Comment: @ Nishant then it will go in the else loop

Comment: @Natasha there is no else loop in your code, for that matter, it is really hard to find else-loops anywhere. A loop would suggest repetitious action. Maybe you meant 'condition'?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `packet.data` is a byte array, you're not specifying an encoding for how those bytes should be interpreted as text - that's almost *always* a mistake. It will use the system default encoding, which would only coincidentally be the right one.

Network packets are inherently *binary* data; if you want to extract *text* from them, you need to understand their structure - including what encoding to use. While you *can* just blindly treat all network packets as ASCII data, it will give you inappropriate results.

Comment: i wrote the contents of "a" in a file and the content is like this            HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2011 13:20:32 GMT
Content-Length: 35
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 19 Apr 2000 11:43:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
Server: GFE/2.0
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: @Natasha: But how did you write it in the file? How much do you understand about character encodings? You *need* to differentiate between binary and text data. Honestly, this *isn't* a problem in Java - it's a problem somewhere in your code and your understanding, but it's hard to help when you don't give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just retrieve your buffer through something like `packet.getBuffer()` or so?

Comment: This should have been a comment and not an answer...